# Failed to initialize an instance of org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.CommonsLogLogChute with the current runtime configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, roboguice

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> org.apache.velocity.exception.VelocityException: Error initializing log: Failed to initialize an instance of org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.CommonsLogLogChute with the current runtime configuration.
```

Error appearing when changing configuration on gradle from target 22 to target 23.
No idea what's that, any ideas?

relevant build.gradle part

```
{
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.package.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Thanks in advance to anyone that will try to help

EDIT: Dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    provided 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.+'
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3.+'
}
```

UPDATE:
The problem is connected to the roboguice library

Comment: which android studio and sdk you are using right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below mentioned value in your app level gradle.

```
android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
.......
}
```